# I have a txt file with a list of numbers in a column. I want to see what numbers are missing and display what numbers are missing

Tags: python

```
workingFile = ("fileOfNumbs")
fp = open(workingFile)
```

This is as far as I have got.  I have tried many different ways I could think of but none have worked.

Comment: A text file with column? What is the format of text file?

Comment: you are just opening the file here. what is it you tried that is not working.

Comment: Downvoted because no proper python code, attempt or basic knowledge at all. If you have tried many different ways, you could at least show them to us so we can lead you the right way.

Comment: Could you show us the text file and explain what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the text file looks like, so I'm gonna guess:

If the text file is like this:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Then you could do something like this:

```
required_numbers = range(max_number)

f = open("fileOfNumbs.txt", "r")
data = f.read()
f.close()

for i in data.split('\n'):
    if int(i) not in required_numbers:
        print(i)
```

Output:

```
3
```

Comment: My text file looks like 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 13.  The numbers are in order just some may be missing.  It contains about 4k numbers.  I want to display the numbers that are not in the file If I set a max number range.

Comment: @Redbullz By missing, do you mean sequentially from 0 to max number? for example, 3 is missing from 1, 2, 4, 5, ...

Comment: @Redbullz I have updated my answer. Please replace 'max_number' inside range() with an integer. Then it will check numbers from 0 to that number you set and print the missing numbers

Comment: @Redbullz In your text file, are the numbers separated by commas or new line? Or comma and a space?